# Explain why show Warning Unchecked cast source.readArrayList(data!!.javaClass.classLoader) as ArrayList<Data>?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

```
 this.data = source.readArrayList(data!!.javaClass.classLoader) as ArrayList<Data>?
```

Warning Unchecked cast: ArrayList<(raw) Any!>! to ArrayList? 
Data for coustom data class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you cast, the compiler inserts a runtime check to see that this cast is valid. For instance:

```
val s: String = f() as String
```

Will have a `checkcast` instruction in the resulting bytecode:

```
checkcast java/lang/String
```

This is a runtime check to see if the result of `f()` is actually a `String`.

But since generics are erased, an `ArrayList<Data>?` will just be an `ArrayList?` at runtime.

So the best a VM can do is check that the value you're casting is an `ArrayList?`, but it can't check if it's actually an `ArrrayList<Data>?`, and that's why the cast is called 'unchecked'.

So for:

```
val a: List<String> = f() as List<String>
```

You will get just get:

```
checkcast java/util/List
```

Notice here how `String` is missing.

However, that does not mean that the VM blindly treats any value you take from the list as a `String`, it usually just means that the cast to `String` happens somewhere else. For instance, when you take something out of the list:

```
val s: String = a[0]
```

This becomes:

```
iconst_0
invokeinterface java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
checkcast java/lang/String
```

Notice how there is a `checkcast` to `String`. That cast is implicitly inserted by the compiler, as if the code were actually:

```
val s: String = a[0] as String
```